# EmbedeedResource custom font is not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, fonts

I have uploaded a font into a Fonts folder that I myself created.
ExportFont attribute is in `AssemblyInfo.cs`, exporting the font and giving it an alias of Yanone.

The font itself is an embedded resource.

Yet when I try to set it from xaml or from code, nothing changes

[image: Project Structure]

[image: The attribute]

[image: the font does not change]

Comment: Did you set the font build action as EmbeddedResource?

Comment: Yes, i did it as soon as i put it into the project. And the copy actions is set to Copy If newer

Comment: Does this help ? [Embedded Fonts: Custom Fonts in Xamarin.Forms](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/embedded-fonts-xamarin-forms/)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the font file has loaded before using. The font file may not have loaded before being used. You can manually load the font file by calling the following code before using it.

Try this and debug,

```
Assembly assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly; 

Stream fontStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Namespace.Fonts.YourFontName.ttf"); 

// set the font family
myLabel.FontFamily = FontFamily.FromStream(fontStream);
```